# AndEngine background displayed as a triangle

Tags: android, andengine

I'm new to AndEngine and I'm trying to implement hanoi game following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12065/how-to-create-a-simple-android-game).
After inserting the background image to the gfx folder, and setting up all onCreateResources code and onCreateScene code, I tried to run the app, and all I can see is a triangle representing my background image, as you can see in [this image](http://i50.tinypic.com/1gji14.png).

[image]

Here is the my code:

```
    final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;

    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        myCamera = new Camera(800, 480, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(false, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                myCamera);
    }
    public ITextureRegion texture;

    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)


        throws Exception {
            try {

                // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
                ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(
                        this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                                return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
                            }
                        });
     // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
                backgroundTexture.load();
    // 3 - Set up texture regions
                this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory
                        .extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);

         }

public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {

        // 1 - Create new scene
        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
    }
```

Since I've tried to solve this error on my own, I've already tried:

1. setting the camera FillResolutionPolicy(),  with no effect on the outcome.
2. Create the background as a BitmapTextureAtlas, BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset
3. calling mEngine.getScene().setBackground instead of attachChild
4. Recreate the Android virtual device with another API levels (tried 16, 15)

Also, there's a thread in the AndEngine forum, [this one](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/need-help-with-sprites-t8812.html) in which I didn't find my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code

1) In  `myCamera = new Camera(800, 480, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);`
first and second argument is for position x and y. So you should do like

> myCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

2) In CameraOptions use

> new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, 
>       new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), myCamera);

3) To load a BitmapTexture you should use `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory`

for example.

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
BitmapTextureAtlas bitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
        getTextureManager(), width_of_image, height_of_image,
        TextureOptions.BILINEAR //Or any TextureOpion you want.
);
ITextureRegion texture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
    .createFromAsset( bitmapTextureAtlas, this, "file_name.png", x_position, y_position);

bitmapTextureAtlas.load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
myCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

instead

```
myCamera = new Camera(800, 480, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like some OpenGL issue. Take a look at RenderOptions, you can get them by calling `engineOptions.getRenderOptions();` There you can tweak the various rendering options.

Anyway, your Camera constructor is very weird, what are you trying to accomplish by that? The usual parameters are as driver613 said. Also, you seem to have the values of CAMERA_WIDTH and CAMERA_HEIGHT swapped. If I am not mistaken, Android handles the device orientation so that width really corresponds to the width of the device in its current orientation.

Comment: I used the camera constructor i found in the tutorial...
I tried to swap the width and height parameters, no change.

Comment: Try tweaking the RenderOptions then, there aren't many of them. Maybe you should improve the question with the following information: Are you using GLES2 or GLES1 version of AndEngine? Does this happen on real devices? What about different screen resolutions?

Comment: I tried it only on several emulators with several screen sizes, no change.
I didn't try it on real device... even if it would work it won't help me debug.

I'm using GLES2

Comment: Well, debugging on a real device is as good as on emulator, if not better. Your problem may be caused by buggy GLES2 support for emulator. I've had rendering problems happen only on emulator and different problems only on a physical device, and that was with GLES1. If you have a friend with Android phone, just try giving them the .apk and see what happens. Or upload it on the internet and let us test it.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue may be here

```
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
```

You are never calling the `pOnCreateResourcesCallback` - you should do that at the end of your `OnCreateResources` method.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when / if your textureAtlas is too small to hold all textures. Check if all textures do find place in it. For example if you have one row of 10 textures with 10x10 px and your atlas is only 90 (or smaller than 100px) wide or less than 10px high. If you have doubts, just try a sufficiently large size and see what happens :)